Why does Expand messes up with multiplication when I clear the orderless attribute?
If I clear the commutativity of *:
ClearAttributes[Times, Orderless]

I get that ab and ba are different now. Why is it that when I order Mathematica to compute:
(a + b) c // Expand

It yields ca + cb instead of ac + bc? How can I make it work so that it yields the latter? It seems to me that this happens because the way Expand works.

I think it is just the final display is based on letters chronological ordering which Front end uses for display. If you do ClearAttributes[Times, Orderless]; (a + b)  c // Expand // TraditionalForm then you get same result as before which is ac + bc but no time to investigate more.

As stated in the documentation, "Orderless is an attribute that can be assigned to a symbol f to indicate that the elements Subscript[e, i] in expressions of the form f[Subscript[e, 1], Subscript[e, 2], [Ellipsis]] should automatically be sorted into canonical order." Consequently, if you remove the Orderless attribute, the sorting does not occur.

Expand might be using internal code that bypasses Times, hence fails to respect the changed attribute.

(a + b)  c // Distribute?

Actually, I sometimes get a c + b c: https://i.sstatic.net/4aJN4RfL.png - Is it a bug?

@Goofy Did you run ClearAttributes[Times, Orderless]?

Did you look at the image of the code I ran?

@Goofy Ah, I missed it. Sorry.

No problem.. :)

I recommend using ** (NonCommutativeMultiply), instead of modifying the attribute of Times.
(a + b) ** c

(* (a + b) ** c *)

Distribute[%]

(* a ** c + b ** c *)

c ** (a + b) 

(* c ** (a + b) *)

Distribute[%]

(* c ** a + c ** b *)

